# Is Egypt currently safe for Americans 2014/2015?

Tags: safety, us-citizens, egypt

I plan on taking a trip to Egypt in 2015. We would hit all the major places, such as Cairo, Luxor, Aswan, Alexandria. Typical tourist stuff really.

With the current state of the world (ISIS, etc), would Egypt be considered safe right now?

Comment: You might want to add more details regarding what you deem being safe means. What are you afraid might happen?

Comment: 2015 is a long time, are you leaving in January, or in June? You say you are leaving in 2015 but are asking for "right now" - not sure your question is worded the best it could.

Comment: I apologize for not being more specific. April, 2015 is the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, nobody here is psychic, so cannot predict what will happen to you. So much so that it's almost closeable as opinion-based.

However, as with many previous times when this question has been asked, [The State Department of the US](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/country/egypt.html) has a comprehensive website detailing the latest information on the country. It points out that while crime is relatively low, there has of course been several incidents of protests, riots and political upheaval over the past year. Demonstrations have resulted in deaths, and in particular, there have been some awful incidents involving women.

> Protests and public disorder are not confined to Cairo and Alexandria.
>   Sohag, Suez, Port Said, Fayoum, Minya, Qena, Asyut, and the Sinai
>   Peninsula have also witnessed incidents of political violence.

Highly recommend reading the page yourself, and in the end only you can make the decision.  Personally, I'd go, but I'm a reasonably experienced traveller and am ok with taking risks. I wouldn't let my parents go on their own.

In the end, as the state department website says, "There is nobody better at protecting you than yourself.". Be careful, keep informed, be safe.

Comment: The corresponding British Government travel advice page is [here](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/egypt).